# re.findall() not returning all matches?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
This$#is% Matrix#  %!
```

I am trying to catch on substrings where special symbols/spaces occur between alphanumeric characters. For eg, my goal is to find these 2 set of substrings: `This$#is` (special symbols #, $ between 'This' and 'is') and `is% Matrix` (special symbol % and whitespace between 'is' and 'Matrix').

My regex findall is as follows:

```
match = re.findall(r'([\w]{1,})([\s\W]{1,})([\w]{1,})', temp)
```

It is returning me: `[('This', '$#', 'is')]` but not the second part `('is% Matrix')`. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

If I change my string to 'is% Matrix' and apply the same regex pattern, I get this: `[('is', '% ', 'Matrix')]`.

Comment: `re.findall()` doesn't return overlapping matches; the `is` cannot be returned as part of both matches.  One possible solution would be to make the third group a lookahead assertion, so that it doesn't actually consume the text as part of the match - thus leaving it to be the first group of the next match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead on the part you would like to have overlapping matches:

```
match = re.findall(r'([\w]{1,})([\s\W]{1,})(?=([\w]{1,}))', temp)
```

`match` becomes:

```
[('This', '$#', 'is'), ('is', '% ', 'Matrix')]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2PJmlX/1